# LinkedIn API v2 is not returning full profile data

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm updating my application to use the LinkedIn API V2  and OAuth 2.0,. The changes works as expected retrieving the basic data (r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress)

However,  I need retrieve some fields related to full profile (e.g, skills, educations) and others that previously were into the r_basicprofile (positions), but that fields are missing in the linkedIn response. here's the call that I'm using to get the data

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,educations,skills, positions)&oauth2_access_token=ACCES_TOKEN
```

And here's the response that I'm getting

```
{
  "firstName" : {
    "localized" : {
      "es_ES" : "Johan"
    },
    "preferredLocale" : {
      "country" : "ES",
      "language" : "es"
    }
  },
  "lastName" : {
    "localized" : {
      "es_ES" : "Rincon"
    },
    "preferredLocale" : {
      "country" : "ES",
      "language" : "es"
    }
  },
  "id" : "MY_LINKED_IN_ID"
}
```

My linkedIn app currently is working with the old API V1 and  already has access to the r_fullprofile, so, with API V1 I'm getting the full profile fields as expected.

I've researched some hours, and the difference with other cases is that my app already has access to full profile (granted from V1)

My questions are:

1. Am I need request again access to the full profile ?
2. Am I doing some wrong for the API V2?

Here's the attachment where I'm verifying that I'm requesting the expected scopes

[Requesting litle profile, email and full profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgS3l.png)

Comment: Hey, are you getting r_emailaddress along with r_liteprofile? in above sample response you didnot mention email field.

Answer (score 3):

In V2 for using r_fullprofile you have to apply for partner program 
after approval only you can use r_fullprofile

Comment: Thanks @KPsingh , my linkedIn app (App 1) already  has access to r_fullprofile due to was applied the partner program in the past and was approved (Using API V1 it works), Do you know if I must apply again? this it not clear for me

Additonally,  I've tested the same code using  other  linkedIn app (App2) that has not access to r_fullprofile and getting the authorization explicitaly the following error is returned "Scope r_fullprofile is not authorized for your application", so, I suspect the error for with the App 1 of linkedin is not related to missing access to full profile

Comment: @JohanRincon If you do not have access to v2 r_fullprofile, you must reapply to a partner program.

Comment: @christopher-ou thanks for your response. Based on my previous tests looks that my app has access to full profile V2 (In the V1 already has access to that scope). When I request r_fullprofile using V2 with an app that has not access  to that scope, the authorization request returns an error, but, with my App 1 (that already has r_fullprofile access) the authorization code using that scope works as expected. so, Will be possible has access to r_fullprofile in V1 but not in V2 with the same app?

Comment: @JohanRincon yes, it is possible to have v1 r_fullprofile, but not v2 r_fullprofile within the same application.

Comment: @ChristopherOu thanks. I've talked with the client to re-apply for the fullprofile permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the API with field projection like this:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,firstName,lastName,educations,skills,positions

According to the documentation you should request the required fields this way:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/projections

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, already tried that, but in that case the following error is returned `{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"not enough permissions to access field skills for GET /me","status":403}`

Comment: And if your just request id, firstName,lastName,educations like https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,firstName,lastName,educations?

Would be great if you could test it, I'm curious if it works.

Comment: it means your old permission was for V1 only So your have to apply again  in V2 for r_fullprofile

Comment: @PetervanMourik this is the result `{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"not enough permissions to access field educations for GET /me","status":403}` . Thanks

Comment: Hi Johan, thanks for sharing. I think KPSingh is right and you need to reapply for the new v2 API. Best of luck, hope you will be approved soon!

Comment: Thanks @KPSingh for your help. I'll let you know  the results after apply again to the partner program.

Comment: Thanks @PetervanMourik. I'll let you know the results after apply again to the partner program